# organizing a git repo for a huge legacy code base

Tags: git, perl

I have inherited a huge perl-codebase. The developers (we are a 3-people team) currently do their "versioning" via backup-files (file.001, file.002 [...] and file is a softlink to the most recent version) I earned the task of implementing proper version control. I choose to take git as it is most flexible and I want to adapt [nvie's git-flow branching strategy](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) as it suits the way they work here.

My Problem is, I don't know how to properly organize the Repository. We have three directories where our code is stored:

1. A directory for deamons. This contains ~200 individual deamons. 90% of them have no dependencies with each other. Deamons are between 4000-10.000 lines of code
2. A directory for tools. Tools contains ~400 programms. Again, most of them are not related
3. A directory with self-written Modules. Some of these have dependencies to the deamons (e.g. when changing a module interface/subroutine you have to change some deamons as well). Those some up to ~150.

Additionally:

1. There is one directory where all config-files reside
2. There is one directory where all testcases reside

I thought of creating a git repository for each of these directories.

Following Problem:
Two persons work on two deamons in the development branch, one is finished working, one is still busy each of them has commited their changes. Now you cannot merge stable versions to master, as you would also push the half-baked version along with the finished one. As far as I know, its not possible to only push individual files.

Normally, one would organize git repositories per project. In our case that would mean creating ~800 repositories, one for each deamon, one for each of our tools, one for each module. I get the feeling that this would be really hard to manage, although it would somehow solve the merge-to-master problem.

Has somebody any experiences with those kind of problems? Any hints? I would also appreciate a hint for a good book on the subject.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the feature branches.

Comment: Do you have any arguments against putting everything in one huge repository starts, so they get used to git (which usually takes some convincing, although it's not very hard)? Afterwards you can think about next steps.

Comment: I agree with one of @simbabque's comments - throw everything into 1 repo to start, or possibly 3-5 repo's, based on the directories you outlined.  It doesn't really matter that most files are unrelated to each other.  You don't want 750 different projects/repo's, especially since referring to files in other project/repo's would require you to use git submodules, and that's a complexity you just don't need to start.

Comment: I know that 750 individual repos is a bad idea. I am searching for a solution when there are changes in two unrelated programs in the development branch. When one pushes to master, both changes get incorporated. That may not be desirable. I don't understand yet, how the feature-branches will help me here, as far as I understand them, you use them for features for future releases - and for the next release you work in develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to git-flow those two developers work on feature branches. If the dev is finished he merges the feature branch to the devel branch, so the devel branch should always be stable enough to be merged, shouldn't it?

Comment: Just for clarification: you suggest doing all development work in individual feature branches? wouldn't that make develop just a copy of the master branch?

Comment: No, as far as I understood git-flow, master just gets the merges for finished versions from release- or hotfix-branches. On develop you collect ready feature-branches and fixes until you think a release branch is due.